# GWT source maps in production

Tags: gwt, source-maps

GWT supports source maps in super dev mode. Unfortunately, they seem not to work in production mode, despite the fact that I added source maps option to my *.gwt.xml file.

How to enable them there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at how this is done for GWT's own website: https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt-site-webapp/+/master/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/site/webapp/GWTProject.gwt.xml, specifically the `includeSourceMapUrl` configuration property.

Note that `-saveSource` is passed to the GWT compiler too.