# GWT web workers and super dev mode

Tags: gwt, web-worker, gwt-super-dev-mode

Is it possible to use web workers with GWT super dev mode? Are there any workarounds for this?

I tried using source map in production mode ([GWT source maps in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28890701/gwt-source-maps-in-production)) but it didn't work out.